# terraform use specific value from for_each in another resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is there any way to select specific value from for_each in another resource section?

With the following I am able to create multiple target_groups without any issues.

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "target_group" {
  for_each = var.target_group
  name              = format("%s%s-%s","TG-",var.name, each.value.incoming_port)
  port              = each.value.incoming_port
  protocol          = each.value.incoming_protocol
  proxy_protocol_v2 = false
  vpc_id            = data.aws_vpc.vpc.id
  target_type       = "instance"
}
```

Here my requirement is to create only one listener with forwarding. So I want to select 1 target group arn (Can be the first one or any other) to create below listener resource. Using for_each I can start a loop with all the target_group but that is not the requirement. Tried many times with different approach but no success yet.

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "forward_443" {
  #for_each = aws_lb_target_group.target_group

  default_action {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.target_group[each.value].id == "TG-EX-DEV-7776" ? aws_lb_target_group.target_group[each.value].arn : ""
    #target_group_arn = each.value.port == 7776 ? each.value.arn : ""
    #target_group_arn = element(aws_lb_target_group.target_group[each.key].arn, count.index)
    #target_group_arn = local.value
    type             = "forward"
  }

  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.lb.arn
  port              = 443
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-FS-1-2-Res-2020-10"
  certificate_arn   = aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn
}
```

in simple, i wanted to create 3 target_group and attach one forward rule to one of them only. terraform should not look for other target_group's

Comment: "ried many times with different approach but no success yet" - what does it mean? What exactly did you try? What errors do you get?

Comment: While tried without [each.key] it is asking to use it but while using, its saying, I can not use it inside default_action sub section

Comment: Can you provide exact error messages in the updated question.

Comment: in simple I wanted to fetch only one value from the list of resource created using "aws_lb_target_group"

Comment: `target_group_arn = element(concat(aws_lb_target_group.target_group.arn.*, list("")), 0)` could you try it? also remove the `for_each` of the `aws_lb_listener`.

Comment: @juanfontes - while using this, getting below error:

``Error: Missing resource instance key
│
│   on alb.tf line 91, in resource "aws_lb_listener" "forward_443":
│   91:     target_group_arn = element(concat(aws_lb_target_group.target_group.arn.*, list("")), 0)
│
│ Because aws_lb_target_group.target_group has "for_each" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
│
│ For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
│     aws_lb_target_group.target_group[each.key]``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to get a single value from your `aws_lb_target_group.target_group`, you can use [values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/values.html):

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "forward_443" {

  default_action {
    target_group_arn = values(aws_lb_target_group.target_group)[0].id
    type             = "forward"
  }

  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.lb.arn
  port              = 443
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-FS-1-2-Res-2020-10"
  certificate_arn   = aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn
}
```

Comment: While trying this validation get passed but while creating resource it tries to create for each value and fails because resource already exists. 

``Error: error creating ELBv2 Listener (arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-1:xxxxxxxx:loadbalancer/app/LB-EXP-DEV/ec5a54546465d6): DuplicateListener: A listener already exists on this port for this load balancer 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-1:xxxxxxxx:loadbalancer/app/LB-EXP-DEV/ec5a54546465d6'
│       status code: 400``

Comment: @Rio You can't have pre-existing listeners. All most be created and managed by your TF.

Comment: So, step 1, creating 3 target_group using "aws_lb_target_group" and then referring those in step 2, wanted to create one listener using "aws_lb_listener" with first target_group arn only.

Comment: This is actually worked. I had to remove for_each entry from "aws_lb_listener". I overlooked your example. thank you very much @Marcin